# Where's the boundary between $\mathcal O(10^i)$ and $\mathcal O(10^{i+1})$?

Tags: notation

When we(?*) say that some $x$ is of the order of $\mathcal O(10)$, we imply that it is *not* of order $\mathcal O(1)$ or $\mathcal O(100)$. (Don't we?)

Where are the cutoff points between those orders?

A. $10\le x<100\Longleftrightarrow x=\mathcal O(10)$

B. $5.5\le x<55\Longleftrightarrow x=\mathcal O(10)$

C. $3.16\approx10^{0.5}\le x<10^{1.5}\approx31.6\Longleftrightarrow x=\mathcal O(10)$

D. "Somewhere else."

E. "You are confusing [this] and [that]."

F. $9\le x<90\Longleftrightarrow x=\mathcal O(10)$

---

**Somebody commented to me about $\mathcal{O}(10)$ elephants. How should I read that **precisely**?*

Comment: If this is about [Landau notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_notation) then the answer is E.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Context: Somebody commented to me about $\mathcal{O}(10)$ elephants. (Don't ask, it's physics. :)) How should I read that?

Comment: *Don't we?* No we don't. Note that $10^{100}=\mathcal O(1)$.

Comment: @Gugg: In that case I believe that e.g. $\mathcal O(1)$ and $\mathcal O(10)$ are not mutually exclusive. In your case it is likely that it can be safely substituted with "tens" or "dozens of elephants".

Comment: I wrote a detailed answer about the exact meaning of $O()$ notation, but I deleted it because I think it's not pertinent. Your associate was speaking informally, or perhaps was dressing up their vague statement about elephants with jargon. I don't think there is a precise reading of the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, there is no difference whatsoever between $O(1)$ and $O(10)$, as it was pointed out in the comments. However, certain cases come to mind when this can kind of make sense (always informally).

*Example 1.* First of all, I wouldn't be surprised if someone said $x = O(10)$ and meant that $x$ is a number somewhere around $10$. However, I can't picture myself (ab)using big-O notation like this.

*Example 2.* But there is another case, and this is something I saw people do a couple of times. Suppose that I ask a student this question: you are given an array of $100$ integers, and you are to write a computer program that will sort them in ascending order. Now, a student can answer: "why, this is easy, I can write a program that will do this in $O(100 \cdot \log 100)$ time".

What the student really means is that his program will sort an array of $n$ entries in $T(n) = O(n \log n)$ operations. Of course, this doesn't tell us anything at all about the specific value $T(100)$: it could be absolutely anything.

These are just things that come to mind. Usually situations like example 2 are quite transparent. Whether or not your particular case is like this - I don't know.

Comment: Yeah, but it's so wrong: sorting an array of fixed length is done in (more or less) fixed time, hence $O(100 \cdot \log(100))$ really means nothing more than *some constant*. $O(...)$ is *only* an asymptotic notation, which means there must be some varying input parameter.

Comment: @arbautjc:  Mathematics is a living language, and one cannot exert complete control over street usage. (The question quoted by OP is intended to punish for street usage. Grammar tests do that too. In the long run, it tends not to work.)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean Landau O-big notation, then $\mathcal O(f(x))$ is usable for functions, not constants. By definition,
$$f(x)=\mathcal O(g(x))\Leftrightarrow\exists M:\vert f(x)\vert\leq M\vert g(x)\vert$$
 There's little use in saying $a=\mathcal O(b)$ for some constants $a$ and $b$ because it's always true for any $a$ and $b\not=0$ since
$$\forall a,b\not=0~ \exists M:\vert a\vert\leq M\vert b\vert$$

Comment: Pedantic, but perhaps specify that $b\ne0$? ($0$ is a [constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(mathematics)#Notable_mathematical_constants) as well.)

Comment: @Gugg yes, you're right. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Douglas Hofstadter wrote on this in his Scientific American column long ago.  It is certainly not precise.  His point was that you convert from absolute numbers to logarithmic numbers (to log of log of numbers) as they get bigger.  So "the order of $10$" is probably $5-15$ or maybe only $7-13$.  Order $100$ certainly includes $70$ and $130$, probably $50$ and $150$ but probably not $30$ or $300.$  Order one million is more like $10^5-10^7$ and maybe another factor $3$ beyond that.  Order $10^{100}$ would certainly include $10^{70}$ and $10^{130}$

Comment: Thanks for lifting my spirits. :) Should I take it from the comments and the other answers that he probably didn't use the $\mathcal{O}$-symbol for this (i.e., probably my question's) kind of "order"?

Comment: Never mind, I think I found the column: ["On Number Numbness"](http://userwww.service.emory.edu/~dlinzer/Hofstadter-NumberNumbness.pdf). (It was actually sitting in a book less than a foot away from my head.)

Comment: @Gugg:  Certainly not in the Landau notation sense.  I think it is exactly in the sense I would take "order of 10 elephants"-a number that is "roughly 10".  The question is what the default bounds on "roughly" are.  The above is what feels right to me, but others may disagree.

Comment: @Gugg:  that is exactly the one I was thinking of.  I love it.